# Move Item without copying (using Sitecore SDK)

Tags: c#, sitecore8.2

I am using [Xamarin sitecore sdk](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sitecore.mobile.sdk) which has documentation [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Mobile_SDK_for_Xamarin/1_0/Sitecore_Mobile_SDK_10_for_Xamarin.aspx), for managing sitecore integrations at my organization.

I am able to connect, get items, create items, etc.. . However, I am not able to move an item. I've tried multiple methods such as updating the `parentID` field or setting the `ItemPath`.

When attempting to update the item all I get is a 204 response and an `updated = true` response. However, 204 essentially means there was *nothing* to update.

```
public bool UpdateItem(Guid item, Dictionary<string, string> updatedFields)  //Updated Fields contains one keyvaluepair = "ParentID", "<Guid>" 
{
    using (Login())
    {
        var request = ItemSSCRequestBuilder.UpdateItemRequestWithId(item.ToString())
             .AddFieldsRawValuesByNameToSet(updatedFields)
             .Database("master")
             .IncludeStandardTemplateFields(true)
             .Build();

        var updateItemTask = _session.UpdateItemAsync(request);
        ScUpdateItemResponse response = updateItemTask.Result;

        return response.Updated;  //Returns 204
    }
}
```

**Note:** The Logs show:

> 752 10:17:41 INFO [Sitecore Services]: Ignoring update of parentid on
>   Item {-Guid-}

Comment: I'm confused, your title mentions "copying Sitecore SDK", but that doesn't seem pertinent to the question.

Comment: Move item without copying. IE I don't want to have it copy as that creates a new item with a new item Id in the new spot. I want to move the existing item, not copy, thereby maintaining all aspects of the item such as the Id

Comment: Okay, the title is meant to be read as "move item without copying", and "Sitecore SDK" is just tacked on.  I get it.  Will edit for clarity.

Comment: It's tacked on because it didn't let me make a tag for identifying what I'm using and one doesn't exist

Comment: I can't seem to edit right now.  The title will be clearer if you insert "using" before "Sitecore".  As written it sounds like you want to copy the Sitecore SDK, which isn't accurate.